# Add one day in time from database in django

Tags: python, django, time

Hi,

I need to add some condition on the time base , right now the value of time i am getting from database is like **2012-09-05 05:05:05** and i need to add 24 hours in this.

I need to show **different** content on time base, like for original time i need to show "hi" and after 24 hours i need to show "hello" in the template file.

How can i do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

probably a custom template tag would be a nice way: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters . you could implement your own `deltaDays` tag with parameters, i.e. `{{ date|deltaDays:1 }}`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this as a cheap filter.

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.filter()
def is_at_least_24_hours_ago(value):
    import datetime
    original_date_plus_24 = value + datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
    right_now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if right_now >= original_date_plus_24:
        return True
    return False
```

Then in your template:

```
{% if object_date|is_at_least_24_hours_ago %}
    // It's 24 hours later
{% else %}
    // It's not
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is sample on how to add day(s),

```
import datetime
b = var_name + datetime.timedelta(0,3) # days, seconds

or 

datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

pass the value through view then use if statement in your template